# vim(spf13) config for racket programming language

Tags: vim, racket

I use spf13 as my VIM config for two servers **a** and **b**.
There is a problem that in server **b**, vim doesn't have colour for keyword when I vim a .rkt file.
For example the file name is `temp.rkt`:

```
(define file "hey, I'am a rkt file")
```

the keyword `define` should be colourful but it's not in server **b**.

Both server **a** and **b** use spf13 as config of vim. Racket config works for server **a** but does not work for server **b**.
Why does that happen? 
How to write a config file that vim can colour the keyword for racket programming language?
(also, can I use vim to ask questions in stack overflow?  Thanks.)

Comment: So, what should I use?

Comment: Your own setup, of course.